# HTML/CSS: Probleme with full width

Tags: html, css

I've created this test-page:
http://uploads.dennismadsen.com/width.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="da-DK">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#e0e0e0;">

    <div style="width:1500px;background-color:#ff0000;">Container width a width of 1500px</div>

  <div style="width:100%;background-color:#000;height:100px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The red div is 1500px and the black to 100%.

When the browser window is smaller than 1500px, for instance 1000px, the black box will only be as width as the window. I would like it to fill as much as the above content.

Please note that the red box has a dynamic width. Therefore I cannot set a min-width=1500px etc. on the black box.

Comment: Why not put the red div inside the black div? And leave the width=100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve such a thing, you need an absolute container.

A markup that will work is for example

```
<div style="position:absolute">
   <div style="width:1500px;background-color:#ff0000;">Container width a width of 1500px</div>
   <div style="width:100%;background-color:#000;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: you can also put the absolute on the body if needed.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is wrap the black div with the red one:

```
<body style="background-color:#e0e0e0;">

    <div style="width:1500px;background-color:#ff0000;">
        Container width a width of 1500px<!--this is where you closed your div-->
             <div style="width:100%;background-color:#000;height:100px;">
             </div>
    </div><!--this is where you should close it to make it work-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them both in another div.  Then that div will be pushed to the width of whatever is in it (the red div) and something with a width of 100% will match it